# How to get Full Target String from Shortcut lnk

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vbscript

Please i am trying to get the full target from a shortcut file. I am using the below function

```
Public Function GetLnkTarget(lnkPath As String) As String
        Dim Obj As Object
        Obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Dim Shortcut As Object
        Shortcut = Obj.CreateShortcut(lnkPath)
        Return Shortcut.TargetPath.ToString
End Function
```

For example i have a shortcut .lnk file with the following target:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscript.exe /e:VBScript.Encode Folder/skype.exe
```

When i use the function to get the target from the following .lnk
D:\Shortcut.lnk

```
GetLnkTarget("D:\Shortcut.lnk")
```

i get the following output

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscript.exe
```

So it does not return the full string of the Target as "/e:VBScript.Encode Folder/skype.exe" is missing from the output.

Comment: vbscript is not the same as VB.NET and certainly not related to c#.  that is the targert, the rest are `Arguments` to the target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the `Shortcut.Arguments` property. See here for the reference of the shortcut object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5y78918(v=vs.84).aspx

So your code will be:

```
Return Shortcut.TargetPath.ToString & " " & Shortcut.Arguments
```