# Can I somehow return the target file name from shortcut in C#?

Tags: c#, shortcut, target

Is it possible to get target file's name as a string from shortcut? or you need to grab it when you get the target file PATH? if so how it's done?

Comment: a simple google search leads you to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309779/how-to-get-full-target-string-from-shortcut-lnk

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, but the targeted answer is not the correct one, since implies VB.NET code and Windows Scripting Host. For a C# implementation, see [How to resolve a .lnk in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c-sharp) and [Creating and Modifying Shortcuts](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp).